# Spring boot validation for interfaces and extended ArrayList

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

I am using spring-boot with hibernate validator
I have a controller annotated with @Validated and I want to validate all the params in my APIs.

One of the annotation is not working(I debugged and it just never being checked as if it is not annotated at all).

```
public MyResponse getPolicyCounters(@RequestBody @Valid MyRequest request) throws Exception {
```

The MyRequest class looks like this:

```
@Valid
public class MyRequest{
    boolean shouldSumSubRules;
    private @Valid RulesSelector rules;
```

The RuleSelector class is an interface and looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RulesStaticList.class, name = "list"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RulesDynamicList.class, name = "criteria")
})
@Valid
public interface RulesSelector {
}
```

The RuleStaticList class looks like this:

```
@Valid
public class RulesStaticList extends ArrayList<@Valid RuleReference> implements RulesSelector {
}
```

The RuleRefrence class looks like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = RuleReferenceDeserializer.class)
@Valid
public interface RuleReference {
    RuleReferenceKind getKind();
}

final class RuleReferenceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<RuleReference>  {
    public RuleReferenceDeserializer() {
        super(RuleReference.class);
    }

    @Override
    public RuleReference deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String fieldName = p.nextFieldName();
        switch (fieldName) {
            case "tag":
                return p.readValueAs(RuleReferenceByTag.class);
            case "special":
                return p.readValueAs(RuleReferenceBySpecial.class);
            default:
                throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(p, RuleReference.class, JsonToken.FIELD_NAME, "");
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 implementation for RuleReference one of them is RuleReferenceByTag and it looks like this:

```
@Valid
public class RuleReferenceByTag implements RuleReference {
    @Size(max = 128)
    private String tag;

    public RuleReferenceKind getKind() { return RuleReferenceKind.Tag; }
}
```

I added @Valid annotation everywhere I could but it still does not work.
What am I missing?

Other annotation in with different classes it does work but I could not solve this problem :/